# when kotlin call subclass of abstract java code from different module in android studio IllegalAccessError occur

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
//module A in java

abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class SubClass extends AbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        Log.v("x","-----------------");
    }
}

public class Invoker {
    public void visit(AbstractClass a){
        a.foo();
    }
}



//module B in kotlin

SubClass().foo()            // it works
Invoker().visit(SubClass()) // java.lang.IllegalAccessError occur
```

add public in front of AbstractClass will solve the problem, but i don't want AbstractClass accessed by others. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, a class and its ancestors must all be accessible from the using class. Even though it is allowed in Java, invoking this code from Kotlin will produce an java.lang.IllegalAccessError.

If you check the decompiled Kotlin Bytecode for the problematic call, you get the following in Java:

```
(new Invoker()).visit((AbstractClass)(new SubClass()));
```

There's an explicit cast to `AbstractClass` which is causing the error since it's inaccessible from the calling code. Even though this cast is unnecessary in Java, it is introduced by Kotlin in the compiled bytecode which makes such a call fail. There is no way around this other than making `AbstractClass` public.